# Access item in JSON encoded string

Tags: php, json

First time working with JSON, been stuck for 2 hours on this. I'm trying to access a specific item in a JSON encoded string using PHP, but running into issues.

My code:

```
$json = json_encode($tweets);

$result = json_decode($json, true);

var_dump($result);

echo $result['text'];
```

Output

```
array(1) { 
  [0]=> array(22) {
      ["created_at"]=> string(30) "Sat Jul 20 15:03:15 +0000 2013" 
      ["id"]=> int(1234567) 
      ["id_str"]=> string(18) "1234567" 
      ["text"]=> string(112) "we have a new billing address" 
  }
```

}

I want to access the ["text"] element only. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you want $result[0]['text']

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be as simple as

```
$result[0]['text']
```