# Can't figure out JSON formatting for PHP

Tags: php, json

```
[{"text":"\n        $3.99\n      ","attrs":{"class":"priceLarge"}}]
```

This is how JSON is being returned to me... (using print_r($price) to display)...

I have tried various ways in PHP to access this data, but nothing has worked.

I want the "text"...

Thanks!

EDIT:

**var_dump (as requested)**
    string(96) "[{"text":"\n        $3.99\n      ","attrs":{"class":"priceLarge"}}]"

Comment: Did you [`json_decode()`](http://us2.php.net/json_decode) that first...?

Comment: Try `var_dump($price)` and add that to your question. Will help a lot in answering your question

Comment: @MartyWallace - I had tried, but then had no luck after that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access item in JSON encoded string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18369737/access-item-in-json-encoded-string)

Comment: sorry mario... didn't know how to ask it and "JSON encoded string" wasn't going to be a phrase I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of **`json_decode()`**

```
<?php
$jsonStr='[{"text":"\n        $3.99\n      ","attrs":{"class":"priceLarge"}}]';
$jsonArr = json_decode($jsonStr);
echo $jsonArr[0]->text;
```

Comment: Thanks! (and thanks for realizing your original error, as I saw that one and tried it and it hadn't worked).

Comment: Lol RJ. You were fast.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you've got a JSON string, you need to use [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/json_decode) to translate it into a PHP object first:

```
$json = json_decode($jsonString);
```

From there, you can access `text` from the first object in the data (which is an array, defined by the outer square brackets`[]`:

```
echo $json[0]->text;
//         |     |
//         |     The property text of that first element.
//         |
//         The first element in the array of data.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$string = '[{"text":"\n        $3.99\n      ","attrs":{"class":"priceLarge"}}]';

$obj = json_decode($string);
```

Allowing you to access:

```
print $obj[0]->text;
```

Comment: Thanks... the [0] was what tripped me up.